# Arch Linux stuck at boot after a restart

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, networkmanager, audit

I was just having fun with installing Wayland and customizing it to my liking and when I finally restarted it before I go to bed, it was stuck on the logo. So, I enabled logging for grubs and it's stuck at

```
[ 16.676220] audit: type=1131 audit(1668615179.786:53): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 36.647193] audit: type=1334 audit(1668615199.753:57): prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
```

Those are the two sample lines of the last outputs, there were like at least 3 of each with different log numbers. The two dupes of the first one have `unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher` and `unit=systemd-hostnamed'` I don't know how to troubleshoot this when googling those gives 0 results. What could be the possible solution?

I'm on Arch using Wayland, Hyprland with Nvidia GT 1030

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result but on xorg. What I did to fix:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> so I can get access to the keyboard and console
2. Mounted boot partition because it wasn't mounted for some reason
3. Ran `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux`
4. Rebooted and it was fixed